# C++/CLI: Using one namespace across multiple files

Tags: namespaces, c++-cli

I have an question about creating namespaces in C++/cli.

I want to have 3 own classes in separate files, but I wanted to have it in one namespace.
Is it possible? And how. Or could I just write namespace with same name in each file and would it be all linked together?

Thanks,
K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you answered your own question.  Namespaces are open, they can exist across files and across different assemblies. As you said, just make the namespace have the same name.